# Father of 2 trying to learn web development

Tags: web-frontend

I am a father of 2 in my 30s.  Trying to break into web development.  Recently I have felt like I am burning out through my self learning through various online classes.

Any parents or people with busy lives out there with tips on how to juggle it all?

Any good links to valuable podcasts, books, classes, etc.  Best practices you use that helps you in learning all the technologies.  I feel like I am getting in a rut and want to get out before it gets any worse.  Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Overflow isn’t suitable for this kind of question since it requires opinions and external resources. Please check the [help] on what to ask about here. There may be a sister site with more help on this issue, take a look at them.

Comment: Thank you very much